# Fixed Menu Div Positioning

Tags: css, css-position, html

I want to make a div that has several child elements and all the elements are fixed but I always have problems with window resizing. The parent div spans the page width (100%) but should the div height be a percentage and how should I make the buttons. I know it should be 'my' choice but I don't mean how to do it aesthetically. I mean practically :)
Any JSFiddles apreciated
     Thanks

Comment: absolute and fixed positioning with pixel values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2PGZS/2/ Only pic I could find...

Comment: The buttons are the grey bits and are children of the large grey rectangle (the div)

Comment: I'm trying to make a moving menu navigation system for getting around the site. I haven't added button sources yet or anything fancy. I'm focusing on CSS first

Comment: One that follows you while you scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u should use height:auto!

```
FixedMenu {
height:auto;
position:fixed;
margin:0 auto;
top:0%;
left:0%;
background-color:#444444;
width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aronez/2PGZS/3/

this what you want?

Comment: or start with bootstrap or foundation css and use a basis template with a static menu ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work, though you will be hiding content under the menu bar whenever you load a new page.  Just be sure to add a margin to your content, for example,

```
body {
margin: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PGZS/5/)